# how to disable simple_form when generating devise views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, devise, simple-form

For my rails 3 application I'm using simple_form and devise. As I need to customize devise views I ran

```
rails generate devise:views
```

the forms generated in the views are of course simple_form forms.

This breaks i18n functionality because simple_form looks for translations using simple_form keys instead of devise keys. For example:

```
I18N keys: [:it, :simple_form, :placeholders, :user, :edit, :email]
I18N keys: [:it, :simple_form, :placeholders, :user, :email]
I18N keys: [:it, :simple_form, :placeholders, :defaults, :edit, :email]
I18N keys: [:it, :simple_form, :placeholders, :defaults, :email]
I18N keys: [:it, :simple_form, :labels, :user, :edit, :email]
I18N keys: [:it, :simple_form, :labels, :user, :email]
I18N keys: [:it, :simple_form, :labels, :defaults, :edit, :email]
```

I'd like to disable simple_form while generating devise views so that I can get advantage of preformatted advise locales (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/I18n)

how can you do that?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regenerate your views with Devise I18n views : https://github.com/mcasimir/devise-i18n-views .

This should sort out the paths to your translations.

Comment: thanks for your help. That gem could be really useful if you need a full translation of the devise views but it doesn't work. I mean adding that gem doesn't affect devise behavior while generating the views. `rails g devise:views` still creates the devise views instead of the devise-i18n-views ones: without translations and still with simple_form. I had to manually copied them directly from the gem. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that devise support i18n but only for flash messages. Simple_form also support i18n but for label, hints and placeholders

The two sets of translations are disjointed and doesn't affect each other as I suspected in my question. So no problem to use simple_form with devise

Lastly, a third set of translations comes with the gem mentioned by tigrish. They concern the phrases and words appearing in the views. As I stated above I'd like to use it with simple_form as well but I couldn't even try it as I explained commenting on tigrish's answer.